# React Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

This code below throws an error in Chrome Dev tools but Webpack doesn't report any fault. I am following an online course and the exact same code works for the instructor but not for me. Needless to say, I am very new to react and online coding thus seeking help/advise.[Image showing error in Chrome Dev Tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBJMY.png)

```
import React from 'react';

class ExampleWork extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section section--alignCentered section--description">

        { this.props.work.map( (example, idx) => {
          return (
            <ExampleWorkBubble example={example} key={idx} />
          )
          })
        }

      </section>
    )
  }
}

class ExampleWorkBubble extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let example = this.props.example;
    return (
      <div className="section__exampleWrapper">
        <div className="section__example">
          <img alt={ example.image.desc }
               className="section__exampleImage"
               src={ example.image.src }/>
          <dl className="color--cloud">
            <dt className="section__exampleTitle section__text--centered">
              { example.title }
            </dt>
            <dd></dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default ExampleWork;
```

Comment: map() only works on defined arrays. In this case this.props.work does evaluates to undefined. Make sure your data is being passed to props.

Comment: `this.props.work && this.props.work.map( (example, idx) => { ... } )` provided your data is loaded on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `this.props.work` is `undefined`.

Looks like you're not passing `work` prop to the `ExampleWork` component.

Check the code where `ExampleWork` component is rendered and pass `work` prop to it.

P.S. Consider renaming the prop `works` as it refers to a collection.